# JQuery change Image dynamically loaded from aspx in DIV

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a DIV and loading a Image in that div at runtime from a aspx file as src.

I use JQUERY .Post(..) to post the aspx page and get the Image and load that Image in div by following code.

```
    function UpdateCapticha() {

        $.post("../JqueryCapticha.aspx", {},
            function (data) {                                                                       
                $("div#CapDiv").html(data);
            });

    }
```

I call this function on click of a button and expect a different Image in div as **JqueryCapticha.aspx** is posted everytime. But everytime I get same Image. I think that **JqueryCapticha.aspx** is not getting posted but the Image is comming from cache.

Can someone please suggest me that what should i do so **JqueryCapticha.aspx** is posted everytime and a new Image should come.

Also i tested **JqueryCapticha.aspx** seperatly on browser and it works fine by providing different image on each post.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you think its the cache problem then you can do

```
$.ajaxSetup({
cache:false
});
```

and rest remains same

```
function UpdateCapticha() {

    $.post("../JqueryCapticha.aspx",function (data){                                                                       
            $("div#CapDiv").html(data);
        });

}
```

you can just use following to prevent caching when using `$.post`

```
function UpdateCapticha() {
    var noCache = new Date().getTime();
    $.post("../JqueryCapticha.aspx",{noCache:noCache},function (data){                                                                       
            $("div#CapDiv").html(data);
        });

}
```

[`.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent caching by using the $.ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../JqueryCapticha.aspx",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    complete: function (data) {
       $("div#CapDiv").html(data);
});
```

HOWEVER: the documentation for [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) says:

> Pages fetched with POST are never cached, so the cache and ifModified
>   options in jQuery.ajaxSetup() have no effect on these requests.

So it would seem that this is not in fact your problem. I would advise using Firebug or similar to look at the network requests being sent to determine what is actually being passed along the wire.

Answer (score 0):

Append a dynamic querystring variable to prevent caching:

```
function UpdateCapticha() {
    var date = new Date()
    var ticks = date.getTime()

    $.post("../JqueryCapticha.aspx?ticks=" + ticks, {},
        function (data) {                                                                       
            $("div#CapDiv").html(data);
        });

}
```